# error during XSL Transformation : Execution of the 'document()' function was prohibited

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2015

I have an issue in msbuild v14/vs2015 when calling an XslTransformation task.

*error MSB3703: Unable to execute transformation. Execution of the 'document()' function was prohibited. Use the XsltSettings.EnableDocumentFunction property to enable it.*

yes, I have a call to the xsl document() function in my xslt transformation..
I don't have any error when running the same task from vs2013 and the previous version of msbuild..
I don't use any C# code here, so I can't set the EnableDocumentFunction property and I don't want to remove my document() calls.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add the [UseTrustedSettings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.build.tasks.xsltransformation.usetrustedsettings(v=vs.121).aspx) parameter to the `XslTransformation` task:
`<XslTransformation ... UseTrustedSettings="true" />`

In order to be able to open the project using previous versions of VS, you may use the following *conditions*:
`<XslTransformation ... UseTrustedSettings="true" Condition="$(MSBuildToolsVersion) &gt; 13" />
<XslTransformation ... Condition="$(MSBuildToolsVersion) &lt;= 13" />`

More details can be found [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20160828035255/http://ohnopub.net/discretion/2014/11/document-function-with-msbuild-14-0-task/).

Comment: For future readers, this needs to be done in the `wixproj` file. Open the file and locate `XslTransformation` node and then use the above instructions to modify them.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the accepted answer above, I've written the following LINQPad (VB Statements) script to make the appropriate adjustments to all the `wixproj` files underneath a specified Projects folder so that they can be compiled with older and newer versions of `msbuild`:

```
Const projectsFolder As String = "C:\Projects"

Dim projects = IO.Directory.EnumerateFiles(projectsFolder, "*.wixproj", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
Dim rXform As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegEx("(?m)(^.*\<XslTransformation .*(?=\s\/\>))")
Dim replaceText = "$1 UseTrustedSettings=""true"" Condition=""$(MsBuildToolsVersion) &gt; 13"" />" & vbCrLf & "$1 Condition=""$(MSBuildToolsVersion) &lt;= 13"""

For Each f In projects
    Dim contents = IO.File.ReadAllText(f)
    If Not contents.Contains("UseTrustedSettings=""true""") Then
        Dim replaced = rXform.Replace(contents, replaceText)
        If Not String.Equals(contents, replaced) Then
            IO.File.WriteAllText(f, replaced)
            String.Format("File touched: {0}", f).Dump()
        End If
    End If
Next
```

I'm sharing this here as it may be useful for others, but please make backups first, or if you're using a repository, then review the changes before committing.  This script should be idempotent, in that it won't alter the same file twice if it's run twice.

Comment: Note that if you use the above script, and your `XslTransformation` node already has a Condition tag, you'll need to manually combine them afterward like `Condition="(test1) and (test2)"`, otherwise Visual Studio will have a problem opening the `wixproj` file.  `msbuild` doesn't seem to mind the two conditions, though.

Comment: (And this is why you should really use proper XML editing techniques, and not Regular Expressions to manipulate XML.)